# "Be having one's hair cut" or "have one's hair being cut" in context?

Tags: grammar

Let's say I am at a barbershop and a barber is cutting my hair. Is it natural to say the following?

> I am having my hair cut.

What I am trying to say that at the moment a barber is cutting my hair. If the sentence is correct, would it mean the same if I said the following?

> I have my hair being cut.

Comment: The first sentence is correct. The second is wrong. But you could say: **My hair is being cut.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it natural to say the following?

Let's say you just got a phone call, and you want to tell the caller what you are doing at the moment.

Your first option

> I am having my hair cut.

is natural and grammatical. The following are commonly used too (See this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=having%20my%20hair%20cut%2Cgetting%20my%20hair%20cut%2Chaving%20a%20haircut%2Cgetting%20a%20haircut%2Chaving%20my%20hair%20done%2C%20hair%20is%20being%20cut&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chaving%20my%20hair%20cut%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgetting%20my%20hair%20cut%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chaving%20a%20haircut%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgetting%20a%20haircut%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chaving%20my%20hair%20done%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chair%20is%20being%20cut%3B%2Cc0)).

> "I am getting my hair cut", "I am having a haircut", "I am having my hair done", and "I am getting a haircut"

As Ronald Sole said in the comment, you could say it in the passive voice: "My hair is being cut". I personally think the passive form *(saying this exact sentence over the phone to the caller)* is better suited for a situation when you are in agony - you *don't* want to have your hair cut, but you are being made to.

Your second option "I have my hair being cut" is not idiomatic (at least I have not heard anyone say that).